# Como formatear un string en una posicion fija?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Mi programa trata de buscar enlaces de paginas web Y cuando la pagina es valida la aplicación escribe [+] Found [+] y si el enlace no es valido escribe [+] Error [+] pero cada enlace no tiene misma longitud. Aqui esta un ejemplo de como la aplicación se ve cuando la corro  `foobar.com/test      [+] Found [+]
 foobar.com/test21      [+] Error [+]
 foobar.com/test333          [+] Error [+]`

Como pueden ver la posición del mensaje se mueve porque el enlace es mas largo. Yo quiero que el mensaje de `Found` o `Error` salga en la misma fila vertical así:

`foobar.com/test      [+] Found [+]
 foobar.com/test21    [+] Error [+]
 foobar.com/test333   [+] Error [+]`

Pero no tan cerca del enlace porque puede haber un error que seria si un enlace en mas largo que la longitud entre el enlace y el mensaje `Error` o `Found` 
Aqui tengo mi codigo

```
for i in array:
    try:
        adminpanel = urllib2.urlopen(website+i)
        checkurl = adminpanel.code
        if checkurl == 200:
            print Fore.GREEN+ website+i," ""                                              " +"[+] Found [+] "
            continue
    except urllib2.URLError, checkurl:
        if checkurl == 404:
            print website+i," ""              Not Found :/"
        else:
            print Fore.RED+ website+i," ""                                              " +"[+] Error [+] " + Style.RESET_ALL
```

Comment: Échale un ojo al módulo `logging` para este tipo de cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si conoces todos los enlaces de antemano, que parece que es así, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Imaginando que los enlaces sin el prefijo están en 'array'
array = ['test', 
         'longer', 
         'longest'] # este es el más largo

website = 'footest.com/'

length = max(map(len, enlaces)) + len(website)

for i in array:
    try:
        adminpanel = urllib2.urlopen(website+i)
        checkurl = adminpanel.code
        lenght_url = len(website + i)
        if checkurl == 200:
            print(Fore.GREEN + website+i, 
                  " " * (lenght - length_url) + "  [+] Found [+]")
            continue
    except urllib2.URLError, checkurl:
        lenght_url = len(website + i)
        if checkurl == 404:
            print(website + i," ""              Not Found :/")
        else:
            print(Fore.RED + website + i,
                  " " * (lenght - length_url) + "  [+] Error [+] " + style.RESET_ALL)
```

El código anterior te debería dejar dos espacios al final del enlace más largo y más espacios en el resto de enlaces.

En la parte de tu código añado el número de espacios deseados en cada `print` haciendo uso de la longitud máxima de un enlace y de la longitud del enlace en uso para así poder meter el número de espacios necesario.

***[No he probado el código ya que no tengo un python2.7 instalado en este PC]***

Comment: ya lo arregle muchas gracias me ayudo tu codigo